# Clojure defrecord - how to use it? followup

Tags: clojure

Disclaimer again: I'm a Clojure newbie. Thanks for the help.

My previous question ( [Clojure's defrecord - how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958027/clojures-defrecord-how-to-use-it)) resulted in a working data structure and methods: https://gist.github.com/3353281

Question: Is there a way to avoid passing in my data structure to all of the methods that operate on it? Or is this the way you're supposed to do it in idiomatic Clojure?

Comment: If you're asking two separate questions, it would be more helpful to others (and worth more karma to you, if they're both good) if they were asked separately. Part of the point of StackOverflow is to build a reusable knowledge base, and having questions be clean, succinct, and separate from each other helps in that goal.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I considered splitting it. I felt that my main question was the first one, and the second one was a quick one that probably wouldn't benefit others as much, so I tacked it on.

Comment: Deleted second question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Data should always be passed explicitly.
2. If you're using nested assocs, you should probably be using `assoc-in` instead.

Comment: I tried to get assoc-in to work for this, but failed; can it be used for multiple values?

Comment: I got `assoc-in` to work, but it still needs nested `assoc`s within. Care to provide an example, if it's possible?

Comment: @WesFreeman If you gave inputs and outputs (each able to stand on their own) and asked how best to transform between the two, that would be different; with only what you've given, I can't test my answer for correctness, and thus I decline to provide one.

Comment: I have [admittedly poor] test code in the gist I provided. I'll post a new question.

Comment: Code describing a transform without any known-good sample input is not adequate to use for testing -- I'd have to guess the inputs you're using it against to synthesize a target output, and forcing the person who's answering your question to make guesses or assumptions is not so helpful.

Comment: It had unit tests at the bottom of the gist--all should return true. But, don't worry about it. My new question was answered.